# i can't receive new data from postgresql

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I used knex to have this code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iah8y.png)

but after I insert the book, I receive an empty array. I tried many way but it still not working

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are not inserting anything. Try first hard coding the data to the handler function that you will always insert and when you get it working with static hard coded data, then you can start trying to read data from `req.body`.